# place four picture next to each other in ACM 2 column journal template

Tags: floats, acm, acmart

I wanted to place these pictures like this in ACM journal template
[image]

my current code is this

```
 \begin{figure}
  \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try `\begin{figure*}` for 2-column figure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is similar to the one given to your other question. [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695253/161015)

Add the package `subcaption` and use this code

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.20\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image A}\label{img:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.20\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Image B}\label{img:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill  
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.20\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Image C}\label{img:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.20\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image A again}\label{img:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Wow! Look at all those images!}\label{img:abcd}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: c]