# subcaption subfig packages not working

Tags: subcaption, acm, subfig

I am using ACM ACR 2 column latex template https://www.sigapp.org/acr.html  I tried to put four figures with subtitles/ subcaption but its not working in my template , i think subcaption subfigure packages are not supported in my template.. Right now instead of a, b, c, d its showing figure10, 11, 12, 13 for sub figures.. please help
.cls file

```
\RequirePackage{comment}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}
\RequirePackage{algpseudocode}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht] % Use figure* to span both columns

  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Image A}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Image B} 
  \end{minipage} 
  
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
    \caption{Image C} 
  \end{minipage}  
  \hfill 
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{Image A again} 
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Wow! Look at all those images!}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems, you are not using `subcaption`, because you are neither use `\subcaptionbox` nor `subcaptionblock` nor `subcaptiongroup` nor any other command or environment provides by `subcaption`. So maybe you should replace the `minipage` environment by `subcaptionblock` environment. But this is only guess, because unfortunately you've not shown [a minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). So I suggest: You should read [the `subcaption` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf).

Comment: Please, edit your question and make your code a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: I would also sugest to have a look at section 4 and 5 of the [subcaption](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) user guide on how to use `subcaptionblock` or `subcaptiongroup`.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, it is a  a template the packages are defied in .cls file

Comment: Nobody will be scanning through hundreds of line of codes ... please reduce to the absolutte minimum to show your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Celdor subcaptionblock.sty' not found error while using subcaptionblock

Comment: @user12 Both `subcaptionblock` and `subcaptiongroup` are environments with a slightly different purpose. These are particular solutions among others. IMO enclosing the block of minipages in `subcaptiongroup` would be the most straightforward solution in your case. Probably not the best, though.

Answer (score 0):

This example is based on `sample-sigplan.tex` from [the official ACM Primary article template for LaTeX](https://portalparts.acm.org/hippo/latex_templates/acmart-primary.zip)  [2023/03/30 v1.90 Typesetting articles for the Association for Computing Machinery] with only the package `subcaption` added.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[sigplan]{acmart}

\usepackage{subcaption} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dummy tex

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2023}
\acmYear{2023}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}
    
\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title Is Hope}

\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\begin{abstract}
 \kant[1]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\kant[2-3]

\section{Template Overview}
\kant[4]

\subsection{Template Styles}

Journals use one of three template styles. All but three ACM journals
use the {\verb|acmsmall|} template style:
\begin{itemize}
\item {\texttt{acmsmall}}: The default journal template style.
\item {\texttt{acmlarge}}: Used by JOCCH and TAP.
\item {\texttt{acmtog}}: Used by TOG.
\end{itemize}

The majority of conference proceedings documentation will use the {\verb|acmconf|} template style.
\begin{itemize}
\item {\texttt{acmconf}}: The default proceedings template style.
\item{\texttt{sigchi}}: Used for SIGCHI conference articles.
\item{\texttt{sigplan}}: Used for SIGPLAN conference articles.
\end{itemize}

\section{Figures}

Your figures should contain a caption which describes the figure to
the reader.

Figure captions are placed {\itshape below} the figure.
    
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image A}\label{img:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Image B}\label{img:b}
    \end{subfigure}\bigskip

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Image C}\label{img:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image A again}\label{img:d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Wow! Look at all those images!}    \label{img:abcd}
\end{figure}

Every figure should also have a figure description unless it is purely
decorative. These descriptions convey what’s in the image to someone
who cannot see it. They are also used by search engine crawlers for
indexing images, and when images cannot be loaded.

A figure description must be unformatted plain text less than 2000
characters long (including spaces).  {\bfseries Figure descriptions
  should not repeat the figure caption – their purpose is to capture
  important information that is not already provided in the caption or
  the main text of the paper.} For figures that convey important and
complex new information, a short text description may not be
adequate. More complex alternative descriptions can be placed in an
appendix and referenced in a short figure description.

\section{Research Methods}

\subsection{Part One}

\kant[2-3]

\subsection{Part Two}

\kant[4]

\end{document}
```